# How to take a space separated string input as key for OrderedDict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddict

I have given some n input lines. Each line contains the name of a product and it's price as integer separated by spaces. I have to store them in an `OrderedDict` with `item_name` being key and `item_value` will be value so that I can remember the input sequence. But in some cases item_name is also separated with space. That's why I'm not able the separate that string and int value. How can I do so?

For example, Input will be like this

```
9
BANANA FRIES 12
POTATO CHIPS 30
APPLE JUICE 10
CANDY 5
APPLE JUICE 10
CANDY 5
CANDY 5
CANDY 5
POTATO CHIPS 30
```

How can I take input as

```
d['BANANA FRIES'] = 12
```

Comment: Will the number always be at the end of the line? Use rsplit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes

Answer (score 0):

```py
parts = line.split()
value = int(parts.pop())
d[' '.join(parts)] = value
```